# Update data in isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I have a code that adds email id and name in Isolated space. But it is not able to add multiple data. Also, how can I update in case any data was entered incorrectly?

```
namespace IsoStore
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("email", "someone@somewhere.com");
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("name", "myname");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["email"];
            textBlock2.Text = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["name"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by multiple data?

Comment: I would like to save, say for example, 10 email id and name.

Answer (score 3):

Cleaned up your code a little for you, using a helper method to do the store:

```
namespace IsoStore
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private IsolatedStorageSettings _appSettings;

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;                
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SaveSetting("email", "someone@somewhere.com");
            SaveSetting("name", "myname");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBlock1.Text = (string)_appSettings["email"];
            textBlock2.Text = (string)_appSettings["name"];
        }

        private void SaveSetting( string setting, string value )
        {
            if (_appSettings.Contains(setting))
            {
                _appSettings[setting] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _appSettings.Add(setting, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try a few other examples to get your head around using IsolatedStorageSettings.

- [How to: Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- [All about WP7 Isolated Storage - Store data in IsolatedStorageSettings](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings)

Comment: And How to retrieve this data?

Comment: @Mansinh: Create another helper to return the strings (or null if they are not present)

Answer (score 1):

I have in mind 2 options, you either save your data to isolatedStorageFile [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx) OR ,this is what i might do in such case, You save under the key email all your emails as one string separate the emails with a char that is not allowed to be in an email, Coma "," lets say, when needed split your string and retrieve it to whatever makes you comfortable.

```
private void SaveSetting( string setting, string value )
    {
        if (_appSettings.Contains(setting))
        {
            _appSettings[settings] = _appSettings[settings] + "," + value;
        }
        else
        {
            _appSettings.Add(setting, value);
        }
    }
```

please note that this code segment is copied from HiTech Magic' answer.

Comment: Not very useful if the same email is saved twice... Also cutting and pasting from another answer (including my *settings* typo) without reference, just to add a slight modification, is considered plagiarism...

Comment: i thought the ultimate goal is to help each other anyhow my apologies. i copied your answer because it is how i would do it, i can delete the answer if you feel like it. Duplicate entries can be handled with ease. there is another option as well!

Comment: Helping is not the issue. Reference anything you copy from others or you will have problems on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and very sorry for not referencing you as the source. will definitely keep this in mind.  is it good this way?